What does calling requestAnimationFrame recursively do?
In this code block what does requestAnimationFrame do?
  tick() {
    if (this.running) {
      this.remaining = Math.max(0, this.end - Date.now());
      requestAnimationFrame(() => this.tick());
    }
  }

In other words what would be the difference between the above code an calling this.tick() outside of the requestAnimationFrame():
tick() {
    if (this.running) {
      this.remaining = Math.max(0, this.end - Date.now());
      this.tick()
    }
}

For reference this code sample is from the What is Lit web component timer example.

It'll wait until the next draw event to call the tick function again. Without doing this it'll just hog the main ui until you get an stack overflow

The 2nd example is pure recursion but the 1st the calls happens asynchronously since requestAnimationFrame calls the callback before the next repaint. It is called in a recursive form to create the animation effect since it only calls the callback once.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame

Is there a way of ... "Visualizing".... over time ... this somehow ... ?

You can create a basic animation with it to see it in action, it basically runs the function 60 times per second. It is how you would animate in <canvas> instead of using hacky things like setTimeout

So wrapping this.tick() in requestAnimationFrame slows down the rate at which this.tick() is called ...So somehow ... the browser determines ... when the next draw event should occur ... and schedules the next tick call to occur then ...?  Is there a more "Exact" way of describing this?

There is documentation on requestAnimationFrame. It does describe the scheduling and when...

OK ... So basically ... if the refresh rate is 60Hz ... Or 60 cycles per second ... that's how many times the tick() callback would be called, every second, until the animation finishes ... and we we did it outside of that it would be called at a much higher frequency ... ?

Jake Archibald did a good video (with animation of the Event loop) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Using recursion without setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame just block the thread and hangs a browser.
requestAnimationFrame schedules the callback just before repainting updated DOM and you can measure FPS like this:


let running = false;
let start1;
let counter = 0;
function tick() {
  if (running === false) return;
    counter++;
    $text.textContent = Math.round(1000/(performance.now()-start1)*counter) + 'Hz'
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
function start() {
  if (running) return;
  running = true;
  counter = 0;
  start1 = performance.now();
  tick();
}

function stop() {
  $text.textContent = '';
  running = false
}
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
<div id="$text"></div>



